# Why can I not type certain upper case accented letters using the option key with Turkish input?

Tags: keyboard, input-source

My macOS is configured with `Turkish Q - Legacy` input source.  To get accented letters, typically one would type `Option + <key>` to get the accented version of it, e.g., `Option + C` to type `ç` or `Option + Shift` + `C` to get `Ç`.

However, this `Option` + `Shift` combination for upper case letters *DOES NOT* work for some letters, even though the lower case version works just fine.  Also, I can press and hold `Shift + <key>` to get the accented letter mini menu to appear on top of the typed letter.  This, thought, is a major typing speed impediment.

**What can I do to be able to type *all* the upper case accented Turkish letters on my keyboard?**

Examples where upper case accented letters CAN be typed with `Option + Shift`:

`Ç`
`Ğ`
`Ö`
`Ü`

Examples where upper case accented letters CANNOT be typed with `Option + Shift`; no output is produced in the app/document:

`İ`
`Ş`

Examples where even `Press+Hold+<key>` does not bring up mini menu above letter:

`İ`

Now all of the above works for the lower case version of the same letters, i.e., hold `Option` and type `s` to get `ş`.

Comment: What do you get instead of İ and Ş? Setting my UK keyboard to Turkish produces exactly what you say should happen, for both lower & upper case. You can test using the keyboard viewer in the language menu. If the letters show there but don't appear, possibly you have something assigned to those as shortcuts?

Comment: It works fine for me.  What version of MacOS are you using?  Do you see this in all apps including Mail, Safari, Notes, Message, Pages, TextEdit? With different fonts?

Comment: @Tetsujin no output is seen in the app or document.  It's as if I didn't type anything.  Same result using keyboard viewer.  Funny enough, I thought that is the one tool that would always make it work.

Comment: @TomGewecke using macOS 10.15.7.  Seeing this in all apps, all standard fonts.

Comment: The keyboard viewer will actually also send to a key command if there is one - you can test simply with Cmd c or v for copy paste

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to tips from @TomGewecke, I was able to find the app/shortcut key combo that took over the letters I was trying to type.

Amethyst (a great window management tool) uses `Option + Shift + I` to "Display current layout" and `Option + Shift + S` to "Select Wide layout".

[image]

I don't have any use for those functions, so I removed the corresponding shortcuts.

For future reference, I am wondering if there is a way to ask macOS for "the list of currently assigned shortcut keys and what app has defined them".

Comment: If you have got your answer, then consider ticking it as accepted answer, then it would be easier for others to see all the unanswered questions.